# Cant debug in eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I am trying to debug a code using f5 and started step by step debugging. But when I pressed f5 in the next step the breakpoint moves to thread class and then to threadgroup class. It iterates to many steps.

[image]

Here `l.add(edg)` its an object for user defined class.
When I started debugging by pressing f5 in the next step I got

[image]

It continuously iterates through all the thread classes..
Why and what is the problem behind this issue?
How to overcome this problem?

Comment: that is normal behavior for f5. since f5 is step into, you iterate every single possible step so you can see where the error might occur. better use f6 to stay in your class

Answer (score 1):

There are different key for debug code in eclipse.

`F5` To go in code depth

`F6` for line by line in class

`F8` for next breakpoint

`F7` come out from depth.

Try anyone and see result.

Comment: F7 to come out of depth ;-)

Comment: no its not working with my IDE... I tried using F6 but its going to thread class directly..

Comment: Do reset perspective window->perspective ->Reset perspective. Restart eclipse and try again

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with Eclipse.
That behavior is perfectly normal. It means your program throws an exception when executing the line of code.

You can see this as you reach the `getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(...)`. That means you got... an uncaught exception! As it's uncaught, the thread is interrupted and the exception is processed by the default handler.

Your program normally should print it in the standard error output (the console) if you let it run (not step by step).

Probably, your `l` list is not properly initialized and you get an `NullPointerException` but that's just a guess as I don't know what `l`is.
Try to re-run your code. When it reach the step where it crash, check the value of your object (hover it with your mouse or add it to the watched objects list).

Comment: initialized `l` in the constructor

Comment: as `l`and your method are statics, check if your constructor is properly called

Comment: anyway, let your program run then check the error stack trace in the console you find out the type of error. That will lead you to a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should go through some tutorials before proceeding
Please refer the link it could help you of basic understanding of debugging.
 [How to debug in eclipse?](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)